# Add VS Native C++ unit tests to existing project?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

We have an existing native C++ executable project in VS 2015. I would like to be able to run some unit tests on it. So far, all examples that I've found involve adding a separate project which links to the object files from the executable project.

We have a couple of issues with this method, and I'm wondering if there is a way to run unit tests off code in the executable project, instead of adding a separate unit test project.

The issues we have with the separate unit test project are:
1) We have to make sure that the configuration is exactly the same in order to get anything to compile. i.e. defines have to match, include paths, etc.
2) Any change to the project that includes adding output files involves updating the config for the unit test project.

Ideally we could add the .cpp files which implement our `TEST_CLASS` classes to our executable project and run them from there. Is this possible? If so, how.

UPDATE: I've figured out how to add Unit Tests to our executable project, but now every time I try to run a test I get the error "vstest.executionengine.exe has stopped working". When I open the dmp file file:///C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/CrashDumps/vstest.executionengine.exe.14420.dmp

The exception information is simply "The thread tried to read or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access"

Comment: You can do postmortem debugging of the `dmp` file on Windbg. If the corresponding `*.pdb` files have enough info, Windbg will tell you what call  has made the exception to happen.

Comment: The issue is not with our code, as the unit test that we have is just a test that calls none of our code.

Comment: You're not the only one: https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=izwCWeeoOorY8geQjoHoDQ&gws_rd=ssl,cr&fg=1#q="vstest.executionengine.exe+has+stopped+working"&filter=0

Answer (score 0):

The better question would be

> How to test existing executable project with VS Native C++ unit tests

And the answer such as "squeeze unit tests into it" would be completely wrong.

You will need to perform 2 changes: make code that dwells inside of executable project is properly accessible from outside and make a unit test project that tests that code.

- The first thing is to ensure that configuration of all these projects
  would be exactly the same. As you mentioned, trying to synchronize it manually is rather troublesome. However VS offers an easy way to deal with this problem: property sheets. Open Main Menu -> View -> Property Manager. Create a new property sheet with all the relevant project parameters. Apply this sheet to all relevant projects so you will always have configuration in sync.
- Create a separate static library project and move stuff to be tested there. Typically an executable project should have only one translation unit defining entry point and nothing else. Link your executable project to this library so it continues to work. Now the code used by your executable is ready to be used outside.
- Create a unit test project and link it to static library. Now you can write some tests.

Comment: I have to disagree, if this is the only way to run unit tests in native c++ on VS, we'll simply move testing to a different platform. This does not seem manageable. Additionally, MSDN seems to point out that it can be done.